# I don't understand how the following algebraic equation breaks down. I just can't figure out how this answer is devised.

Tags: quadratics

I just don't understand how this equation breaks down like this.
The second step... $[k^2 + k + 2k + 1]$ is perplexing, but breaking that down to $(k+1)(k+2)$ has completely baffled me. I would expect this to be equivalent to $[k^2 + 2k + 1k + 2]$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Equation I don't understand]

Comment: I think the last 1 in the second line should be a 2.

Comment: You can just use $k = 0$ to see it's wrong. Then the first line is then $5$, while the second line is $5/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in what you showed -- it should be $k^2+k+2k+2$, not $+1$. So indeed, you're right to be baffled.

*After* fixing this, here what the derivation does: you have
$$
\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1) = 
\frac{k^2+k}{2} + \frac{2k+2}{2} = 
\frac{k^2+3k+2}{2}
$$
explaining the first step.

Now, you have that $$(k+1)(k+2) = k(k+1)+(k+2) = (k^2+k)+(k+2) = k^2+3k+2$$
explaining the second.

Comment: Thanks.. that now makes sense... damn

Answer (score 0):

You could have directly factored $5(k+1)$ for a shorter computation:
$$\frac{5k(k+1)}2+5(k+1)=5(k+1)\Bigl(\frac12k+1\Bigr))=\frac52(k+1)(k+2).$$